# "flick" an image from an iPad to a screen

Tags: ios, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if the following has ever been done before, ideally in unity.

What I want is to be able to take an image I have on my iPad and send it to a screen to be displayed with a flick gesture. Much like what you do with a window on a computer with dual monitors.

You drag it, and it instantly appears on the other monitor.

if this hasn't been done before, how would you go about making this possible? I know that it is going to require a fair deal of networking if I'm to pass an image from one device to another.

Comment: I suggest before implementing any ideas, first check them with Apple developer agreement. They are kinda about these issues.

Comment: I think you can do this with an android device and a samsung TV (If my memory serves me correctly!) not that that helps you answer this question

Comment: What is driving the screen? A computer, or the iPad, must be driving the screen in question, and the solution will differ according to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends strongly on what do you want to include under the designation of "monitor" in this particular context.

If it's the screen connected to a computer you can theoretically do all this by creating an IPad client application and a computer server application, and using some way to communicate between the two (either direct WiFi, or through internet, etc). Of course you'd need to make specific server applications for the Operating Systems you'd like to target (Windows, Linux, etc).

If the screen is a TV, you should check which are the "smart-enough" ones to allow for an external wireless connection (or maybe wired too if that's what you prefer) that an IPad can use. Then, for each of those TVs you'd have to check what APIs they provide, and if said APIs allow you to access the connectors in the way you want. Then it's the same story as before,  chose which platforms you want to target and create the software for those.

One way you can explore this is with your tablet and computer (either any Android Tablet+Any Computer with any OS or IPad with Apple Computer). Try doing some simple coding, just to see how you can transfer an image from tablet to computer. Once that's done, the presentation part of your IPad application (gallery of images, finger flick support, etc) can be done with Unity.